# regex for validating input C 200 50

Tags: regex

How do i write regex for below?

`C 200 50`

C/c can be upper case or lower case. 
200 - 0 to 200 range 
50 - o to 50 range

All three words are separated by space and there can be 1 or more space.

This is what i tried so far.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input = "C 200 50";
        String regex = "C{1} ([01]?[0-9]?[0-9]|2[0-9][0]|20[0]) ([01]?[0-5]|[0-5][0])";

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);    
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
        boolean found = false;    
        while (matcher.find()) {    
            System.out.println("I found the text "+matcher.group()+" starting at index "+    
             matcher.start()+" and ending at index "+matcher.end());    
            found = true;    
        }
    }
```

Not sure how to have multiple space, upper or lower first 'C'

Comment: Value ranges are a separate question, not supported by regexes in themselves. Did you read up on that topic? Do that first. Also please show what you have already tried. Try to give the impression that you do not mistake StackOverflow for a free code writing service, other wise this is a "requirements, please give code" question and hence too broad to be answered.

Comment: My bad, i've added the code which i tried so far

Comment: Can the `200` value be `000`? Or do you want to only allow a single `0` and no leading zeros?

Comment: 0 or 000 as long as i am able to parseInt java method returns int value. Its fine.

Comment: Try `String regex = "(?i)C +0*(\\d{1,2}|1\\d{2}|200) +0*([1-4]?\\d|50)";` or `"(?i)C\\s+0*(\\d{1,2}|1\\d{2}|200)\\s+0*([1-4]?\\d|50)"`. If you validate the whole string, use it with `.matches()`, not `.find()`. See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hin6wW/4) (I added `^` and `$` to emulate `.matches()`).

Comment: See [this Java demo](https://ideone.com/ash1Oa).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are validating a string, you must be expecting a whole string match. It means you should use `.matches()`  rather than `.find()` method as `.matches()`  requires a full string match.

To make `c`  match both `c` and `C` you may use `Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE` flag with `Pattern.compile`, or prepend the pattern with `(?i)` embedded flag option.

To match one or more spaces, one would use `+` or `\\s+`.

To match leading zeros, you may prepend the number matching parts with `0*`.

Hence, you may use

```
String regex = "(?i)C\\s+0*(\\d{1,2}|1\\d{2}|200)\\s+0*([1-4]?\\d|50)";
```

and then

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/hin6wW/4) and a Regulex graph:

[image]

See the [Java demo](https://ideone.com/ash1Oa):

```
String input = "C 200 50";
String regex = "(?i)C +0*(\\d{1,2}|1\\d{2}|200) +0*([1-4]?\\d|50)";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);    
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
boolean found = false;    
if (matcher.matches()) {    
    System.out.println("I found the text "+matcher.group()+" starting at index "+    
       matcher.start()+" and ending at index "+matcher.end());    
    found = true;    
}
```

Output:

```
I found the text C 200 50 starting at index 0 and ending at index 8
```

If you need a partial match, use the pattern with `.find()` method in a `while` block. To match whole words, wrap the pattern with `\\b`:

```
String regex = "(?i)\\bC\\s+0*(\\d{1,2}|1\\d{2}|200)\\s+0*([1-4]?\\d|50)\\b";
```